# Stranger character appearing instad of "ç" in xamarin for android

Tags: android, xamarin, utf

I am passing parameters and receiving a lot of values back from my webservices one of these values is a string that was suposed to be "Açougue" but im getting something different from that something like "A┌ougue". What can i do to make my app to be able to set that word right?

```
var request2 = new RestRequest (String.Format("?param1={0}&param2={1}", (int)CGI_FUNC.GETSERVICOS, classGlobalVars.usuario));
asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync (request2, response => {
    servicoLista = new List<objectServico> ();
    Console.WriteLine("Something: "+response.ContentEncoding);
    if (response.Content != "") {
    }
});
```

So tried changing my response.ContentEncoding to "utf-8" or something but it didnt worked.

Thanks for all the help. ^^

Comment: Use UTF-8 encoded strings, in strings.xml and everywhere

Comment: Like you said "receiving a lot of values back from my webservices" so its a webservices task to encode strings in UTF-8...

Comment: So i need to make my webservice to send me the string in UTF-8 and just keep the same code for the app? ( sorry not understanding english is not my primary language ).

Comment: I did what they told me in the last question but still this:

A�OUGUE instead of Açougue

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var request2 = new RestRequest ();
request2.AddParameter("text/xml; charset=utf-8", String.Format("?param1={0}&param2={1}", (int)CGI_FUNC.GETSERVICOS, classGlobalVars.usuario), ParameterType.RequestBody);

asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync (request2, response => {
    servicoLista = new List<objectServico> ();
    Console.WriteLine("Something: "+response.ContentEncoding);
    if (response.Content != "") {
    }
});;
```

Comment: I feeling really dumb, i'm sorry i didnt found those on here. I'm updating my question.